# Read in File (Image) for Mocha/React Unit Test

Tags: file, unit-testing, reactjs, upload, mocha.js

I'm using Mocha/Chai/Sinon to unit test my React app, and I'm wondering how to mock a file upload. In my app, I use a traditional `<input>` component to prompt a file upload, which I then read using FileReader.

For the unit test, however, I'm not sure how I can perform this file upload directly, without having to prompt the user to upload a file (since it's a unit test). I'd like to be able to load in a File object, just like I do in my app, and test it for file size, type, etc. **How do I load in a local file and use it as a File object?**

Comment: Hi @frogbandit, can you post your code please?